# Error 500 when I have RewriteMap in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rewritemap

I have a map file in this format

```
233 Alabama/Phenix-City/Ridgebrook
237 Alabama/Ft.-Mitchell/Riverside-Estates
```

I have the following .htaccess script.  I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error when the page in question is hit.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteMap examplemap txt:/var/www/html/site.com/key_pair.txt
RewriteRule community.php?(.*) ${examplemap:$1} [R]
```

When I pass the following URL I wish for it to be rewritten as follows.

```
http://example.com/community.php?comm_id=233
```

should be rewritten like this

```
http://example.com/Alabama/Phenix-City/Ridgebrook
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could just use a relative path, so just txt:key_pair.txt. No other thoughts as to what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Well it looks the site isn't accessible with the RewriteMap rule.  I just tested other pages and can't access any of them.  ONce i comment out the lines from the .htaccess file the site runs.

Comment: I wonder if the RewriteMap goes in the .htacess file or somewhere else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't have RewriteMap in an .htaccess file:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Only usable in server config (like httpd.conf) and your virtual host conf files.

Comment: thanks I figured that out.  Was told I couldn't answer my own question for 8 hours.